# website popup notification

Tags: text, popup

I would like make a popup appear on my site like ones that come up when you facebook friend request someone.  im do not want the javascript alert();.  if possible can this popup notification be triggered from a boolean value from a database? thanks

Comment: Not nearly enough information for someone to actually help you with this, the 'question' sounds like you want someone to do it for you. What have you got so far, and what problems are you facing with it?

Comment: @mdm please dont assume things.  i just wanted a link to get me in the right direction for the project described above.  james gave me exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: You should read http://stackoverflow.com/faq and http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @mdm: Nice link to the Jon Skeet blog post.  I seem to find the most interesting tidbits from links in comments (like yours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) will meet your needs? A search on Google for "lightbox" will get you thousands of useful links.